# Open usercontrol in separate tab in browser

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is there a way to open up a usercontrol (.ascx file) in a separate browser tab/new window?

Google has yielded me no results for this - I've seen people putting them in modals, but this is not what I am needing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create an .aspx page that contains your user control.  Then use _blank as the target to open that page in a new tab/window.

JavaScript

```
window.open(url , '_blank');
```

Link

```
<a href="http://page.aspx" target="_blank" >Link</a>
```